# Siri - location issue

Tags: macbook-pro, siri, geolocation

Siri cant find my location on my macbook, despite having all location services on. Apple maps show my precise location, while google maps dont. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what exactly happens? Google maps shouldn't use Siri to get its location.